# Where is Manage third party OAuth Client access

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Trying to access google admin sdk directory and getting the error:
  AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied
which has been asked before here on stackoverflow and the answer usually points to this document:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account
However, if I follow instructions and go to Security/Advanced Setting on my google domain control panel, I don't have the *Manage third party OAuth Client access* option, and can only see these:

- Manage OAuth domain key
- Federated Login using OpenID
- Manage OAuth Client access

Is there a new document?  Is this restricted to non-free google apps accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Manage third party OAuth Client has recently been renamed to be Manage OAuth Client access it seems.  Go to Manage OAuth Client access in your security setting, and input your client id in the 'client name' field and the scope you want to grant (put in the entire URL. ex: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive 
) in "one or more api scope" field.

Once you click 'authorize', the scope will be granted.

Updated as September 24th, 2014: 
The name has changed to "Manage API client access" from "Manage OAuth Client access".  Thanks for the comment, Fausto@.

Comment: I could swear I tried that and the "client id" was rejected.  Must have copy and pasted the wrong thing.  Submitted feedback on the google document, hopefully they'll update it.  Thanks.